# Trivia Questions with attemps with for loop and while

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues trying to display questions and answers that are stored on an array, while putting an attempt loop. however, the questions dont seem to appear, or store the user input.

Can someone look at my code and guide me on what I am doing wrong? I would appreciate all the help

```
<script>
//display questions on js stored on array
displayQuestions();

var userInfo = prompt(questions[0]);
var userInfo = prompt(questions[1]);
var userInfo = prompt(questions[2]);
var answers = findAnswers(userInfo);

if(answers == "Wrong"){
    document.write("<p>" + userInfo + "is " + answers + "</p>")
} else {
    document.write("<p>" + userInfo + "is right""</p>");
}

var score = triviaQuestions();
document.write('Your score is ' +score);
</script>
```

and here is my js code where i have the arrays and I am trying to create the quiz function that accepts one parameter which is the counter. which will initialize a guesses variable of 3. This will be used to count down the number of attempts the user has to answer the question correctly.

```
var questions = ['What is the first day of the week?','what is last day of 

the week?',
'What is better, an Xbox or Playstation?'];

var answers = ['Monday', 'sunday','xbox'];


function displayQuestions(){
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        document.write(questions[i]);
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}

function findAnswers(match){
    i =0;
    while (i < 2) {
        if (questions[i] == match){
            return answers[i];
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return "Wrong Answer";
}


function triviaQuestions() {
    var score = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        var attempts = 3;

        while(attempts > 0) {
            ans = promt(+questions[i]);

            if(ans == answers[i]){
                score = score + 1;
                alert("Good Job");
                attempts = 0;
            } else {
                alert("Wrong!");
                attempts = attempts - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: You're overriding the previous value of `useInfo`, only the last value stands. Also, in `findAnswers` you should compare the passed answer to the stored answers, not to the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case it makes no sense to me to split up the code into functions:

```
var score = 0;
const questions = [
  'What is the first day of the week?',
  'what is last day of the week?',
  'What is better, an Xbox or Playstation?'
];
const answers = ['Monday', 'sunday','xbox'];


questions.forEach( function(question, i){
  var triesLeft = 3;
  while(triesLeft--){
    if( prompt(question) === answers[i] ){
       alert("right!");
       score++;
       return;// continue with forEach
    }
    alert("please try again!");
  }
  alert("sorry, you had the chance :/");
});

alert("you did a score of "+score);
```

( The forEach can be replaced with a regular for loop. However, then one need to use an else)

Comment: and to convert the user upper to lower case, I just use .toLowerCase   right?

Comment: @xTuckli exactly ;)